# Help ID this South Indian fruit-bearing tree

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

So there's this fruit-bearing tree near my house in [Kerala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala), South India. A senior neighbor of mine tells me that this fruit is edible. I tried it out, and it tastes alright. I want to ID this plant, know its botanical name, as well as whether it has any medical/commercial/culinary application.

[image: The flower, a small, white one.]

The fruit is green when tender and red when ripe.

[image: The fruits, like a red berry when ripe.]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like *Muntingia calabura*, the **Jamaica Cherry**.

[image: flower]
[pic source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muntingia)
[image: berry]
[pic source](http://www.fruitipedia.com/jamaican_cherry_muntingia_calabra.htm)
It is indigenous to tropical America and often planted in Asia.
It is edible and used in jam, cake and fruit drinks. The bark is sometimes used as rope. Source: "Tropische vruchten, Nowak&Schulz 1999"

Comment: Googled it and confirmed. This is what I was lookin' for. Thanks again!